# American Airlines Where We Fly: Understanding their Route Map Interface

Tags: air-travel, american-airlines

When using the [AA Interactive Map](http://aa.fltmaps.com/en) is there a way to get only direct flights from a city?

For example, if I click on Malaga, Spain, it shows a huge web of direct and connecting flights. Is there a way to show only direct flights?

The [answer from this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/maps-showing-routes-of-multiple-airlines) is usefull. Just wish I could use the AA website.

Comment: +1 for just that Interactive Map, I never knew about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press "Destinations" in the top bar; then you get a drop-down where you can *remove* the checkmark from "Add AA Connections".

(Malaga then won't show *anything* because its only AA connections are through codeshares to Madrid or London).

Answer (score 3):

There is a sort by option on the top right of the results modal.  You can select sort by stops, which would list non-stops at the top.  Unfortunately it doesn't change what shows on the map.

Answer (score 2):

www.flightconnections.com is great for this type of thing. You can filter by airline and it shows the route map for this airline.

Malaga shows empty for American, since they don't fly there on American metal. However, you can also select "oneworld" as the airline group, which will likely show you all available code shares as well. This won't be American flights, but you can probably book them through American and combine them with other American flights.